# In CSS, how to compute the percentage height within a `height:auto` parent?

Tags: html, css

CSS

```
#parent {
  height: auto;
}

#child {
  height: 10%;
  width: 75%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    <span>I'm one tenth the height of my parent.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this a forbidden or wrong usage?  This is a bit confusing because child relies on the parent's height to calculate its own height, and the parent also relies on the child's height to calculate the `height:auto`..

How will the browser compute the height for the child and parent element for the above codes?

Comment: In that case browser compute height depend on content of div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is a bit confusing because child relies on the parent's height to calculate its own height, and the parent also relies on the child's height to calculate the `height:auto`..

Exactly, so the browser doesn't bother with the percentage at all. From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-height-property):

> **<percentage>**
>   *[...]* If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'.

So the computed height for both elements is `auto`.